# How to combine two observables based on ID within an array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `combineLatest` to add results from more than one observable to a single subscription to great success thanks to help from other posts, but cannot find an answer to this one.

I am trying to map an observable to another based on a unique id within an array. So I have two APIs giving:

```typescript
    export interface user {
       id: string,
       name: string,
    }
```

and

```typescript
    export interface rules {
       id: string,
       users: Array <{
            string,
        }>
    }
```

and am looking to combine to:

```typescript
    export interface user {
       id: string,
       name: string,
       rule_id: string,
    }
```

or potentially

```typescript
    export interface user {
       id: string,
       name: string,
       rules: Array <{
           string,
        }>
    }
```

Below is my current code

```typescript
    const result$ = combineLatest([users$, rules$]).pipe(
        map(([users, rules]) => {        
            return users.map(user => {  
                const rulesForUser = rules.filter(rules => rules.users.includes(user.id))
                return {
                    ...user,
                    rules: rulesForUser,        
                }
            })
        })
    );
```

And have this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Comment: Could you also add what you've tried so far? Or what went wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: Of course; apologies, I should have done this. Edited original post.

Comment: Can you share how you have defined `users$` and `rules$`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Not sure what you mean - they are API calls. Is the problem likely to be because not all rules responses will have user_ids?

Comment: It will help identify how the Object type is returned, you are experiencing a type error, it is most likely originating from the response Objects (user and rules)

Comment: I see what you mean! Thanks - you have helped me fixed my issue. I changed this: export interface user {
       id: string,
       name: string,
       rules: Array <{
           string,
        }>
    }

Answer (score 1):

I realise now, thanks to Owen Kelvin that I should not have "string" in my types within the expected array:

```
export interface user {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   rules: Array <{

    }>
}
```

Not gonna lie, not sure why, but thanks so much!!